# the method 'toDouble()' was called on a null in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I am trying to get buttons like [this as in the library](https://github.com/flutter-ui-challenges/flutter_web_challenge_googlemaps) so so I tried to make the button as done in this library but I am getting an error I tried looking for the cause and found that it happens when I don't define some value in the double value so I did that but then also I was getting the same error.

ui_helper.dart

```
import 'dart:core';

/// ui standard
final standardWidth = 375.0;
final standardHeight = 815.0;

/// late init
double screenWidth;
double screenHeight;

/// scale [height] by [standardHeight]
double realH(double height) {
assert(screenHeight != 0.0);
return height / standardHeight * screenHeight;
}

// scale [width] by [ standardWidth ]
double realW(double width) {
 assert(screenWidth != 0.0);
 return width / standardWidth * screenWidth;
}
```

MapButton.dart

```
class MapButton extends StatelessWidget {
final double currentSearchPercent;
final double currentExplorePercent;

 final double bottom;
final double offsetX;
final double width;
final double height;

final IconData icon;
final Color iconColor;
final bool isRight;
final Gradient gradient;

const MapButton(
  {Key key,
    this.currentSearchPercent,
    this.currentExplorePercent,
    this.bottom,
    this.offsetX,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.icon,
    this.iconColor,
    this.isRight = true,
    this.gradient})
  : assert(currentExplorePercent != null),
    assert(currentExplorePercent != null),
    assert(bottom != null),
    assert(offsetX != null),
    assert(width != null),
    assert(height != null),
    assert(icon != null),
    super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Positioned(
  bottom: realH(bottom),
  left: !isRight ? realW(offsetX * (currentExplorePercent + currentSearchPercent)) : null,
  right: isRight ? realW(offsetX * (currentExplorePercent + currentSearchPercent)) : null,
  child: Opacity(
    opacity: 1 - (currentSearchPercent + currentExplorePercent),
    child: Container(
      width: realW(width),
      height: realH(height),
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: realW(17)),
      child: Icon(
        icon,
        size: realW(34),
        color: iconColor ?? Colors.black,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: gradient == null ? Colors.white : null,
          gradient: gradient,
          borderRadius: isRight
              ? BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(realW(36)), topLeft: Radius.circular(realW(36)))
              : BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(realW(36)), topRight: Radius.circular(realW(36))),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.3), blurRadius: realW(36)),
          ]),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

So these are the class I used from this library but it is not working so far.
I called it like this

```
MapButton(
        currentExplorePercent: currentExplorePercent,
        currentSearchPercent: currentSearchPercent,
        bottom: 243.0,
        offsetX: -71.0,
        width: 71.0,
        height: 71.0,
        isRight: false,
        icon: Icons.layers,
      ),
```

I tried to run the library it was working fine. any help how to fix this.

Comment: What line of code is the error on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main issue is that you are not providing screenWidth and screenHeight value. if you provide it will solve your issue.

When your widget called it will call realH but screenWidth's value is not define, so it can not calculate value and it can not return value.

```
  screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; 
screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
 if (screenWidth > standardWidth) { 
   screenWidth = standardWidth;
  } 
 if (screenHeight > standardHeight) { 
    screenHeight = standardHeight;
 }
```

Comment: but i am calling the method same way done in the library

Comment: may be they are setting that global variable in someway. you have to figure it out. did you try by setting its default value ?

Comment: solved it by adding screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    if (screenWidth > standardWidth) {
      screenWidth = standardWidth;
    }
    if (screenHeight > standardHeight) {
      screenHeight = standardHeight;
    }

Comment: @NeelaySrivastava can you accept my answer if it works for you.